# How to categorize trust account payments?

Tags: accounting

I have two accounts - a trust account and an operating account.

When I process credit card payments, they go through an operating account and then are transferred to the trust account. These payments are NOT income until I remove them from the trust account when they are earned, which occurs later on . My questions are as follows:

1) How should I categorize these payments in Wave when they are deposited into my operating accounting (currently categorized as income)?

2) How should I categorize these payments in Wave when they are withdrawn from my operating account to my trust account (currently categorized as expenses)?

Comment: Are you on a cash basis, or an accrual basis?

Comment: Accrual basis accounting